# Windows 10 IoT: Serial UART I/O missing. Solutions for RS485 serial I/O?

Tags: windows-iot

Since the Serial UART I/O pins (P1 8 and 10) are not yet supported by Windows 10 IoT, I am looking for alternatives for simple RS485 access via the RPi. As far as I can see, none of the USB to Rs485 converters provide drivers for Windows 10 IoT yet either. The search continues. Any ideas or pointers (in C# or Javascript at best)?

Comment: Pointers in C#? This is really unsafe oO

Comment: SPI and I2C should work.  Can you get RS485 to SPI/I2C?

Comment: Thanks, yes after seeing this limitation I started looking for a SPI or I2C shield as an alternative. No luck finding one yet though.

Answer (score 2):

The latest windows iot build from October 2015 has the onboard serial pins enabled now. You can also go from USb to Usb in some cases with no adapters needed. I have it semi working with a few issues. You can check out this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339074/windows-10-iot-serial-working-on-rp2-but-read-serial-data-incomplete), if you want to take a look at the issues im running into